# Cisco UCS C220 M4 PSU Fault In Diagnostics

Tags: cisco, power-supply-unit, firmware, diagnostic

Hello fellow Sysadmins.

A C220 M4 with the latest recommended firmware I am working on displays the following fault messages on latest version diagnostics at Server Health:

PSU1 PSU1_PWRGD: Power Supply sensor for PSU1, State Asserted

PSU2 PSU2_PWRGD: Power Supply sensor for PSU2, State Asserted

The server has two 770W PSU.

All other subsystems report healthy condition, including CIMC.
I have read on Cisco site that there is a similar bug in v3 firmware and it was fixed. [Cisco Bug](https://quickview.cloudapps.cisco.com/quickview/bug/CSCue67778)

I am using v4.1g firmware.

How to resolve this situation ?

Comment: That server has gone past it's end of support life, no more updates, replace it.

Comment: I disagree: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/servers-unified-computing/ucs-c220-m4-rack-server/model.html
End-of-Support Date 29-FEB-2024

Comment: Fair enough - I mis-read this document - https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/servers-unified-computing/ucs-c-series-rack-servers/eos-eol-notice-c51-741235.html